# Is it possible for us populate field in event based on a custom field in opportunity

Tags: administration

I am trying to see if we can populate a field in event when we click the new event from opportunity.

When we click new event from opportunity, the opportunity get auto filled in the event. Is it possible to do the same for other fields?

When i click on new event on opportunity, this the url which we get

https://ap1.salesforce.com/00U/e?who_id=0019000000AhW9v&what_id=00690000005wyIB&retURL=%2F00690000005wyIB

This passes the whatid into the url, tried to pass subject in the url, it didnt work. Any ideas if this could be achieved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a custom button. Here are the steps:

1. Create a custom button (Setup > Customize > Activities > Event Buttons and Links:
   [image]
   Here's the formula for easy cut and paste. You can see I added &evt5={!Opportunity.Name}. This sends over the opportunity name as the subject:

`/00U/e?who_id={!Opportunity.AccountId}&what_id={!Opportunity.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}&evt5={!Opportunity.Name}`

2. Add this button to your Opportunity page layout. You need to click on the little wrench on the Open Activities section:
   [image]

Then add the custom button and optionally remove the standard New Event button:
[image]